# How to get user roles in drupal 7.x?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I want to get the user roles Just like getting node types using this

```
node_type_get_types();
```

is there anyway to get user roles using a function like this?

Comment: This can be done running a custom SQL query but i want to know a built in function or hook

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See the [`user_roles()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/user_roles/7) function which provides a list of all roles, or you can optionally filter on specific conditions (there are more details on the documentation page I linked to).

Answer (score 7):

If you want to check for a specific role of the current user (in this example we use "authenticated user"):

```
global $user;

if (in_array('authenticated user', $user->roles)){
    //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`user_load()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/user_load/7) to retreive the roles for a user.

example:

```
$user = user_load(1);
$roles = $user->roles;
// $roles contains all the users assigned roles
```

Comment: OP seems to want a list of all roles in the system, not all roles for a particular user

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach to checking roles would be to see if the user has a certain role example.

```
if(user_access('access content')){
   //Good to go....
}
```